# Keeping divs(social icons) centered when removing some

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have some social icons on my wordpress theme I am working on, and I am trying to add the ability to select which icons to use. The problem is that when I remove icons, it automatically will mess up the alignment, because I use an offset on the first icon, and an extra class on another. Now I figured out a way around this(although not working as of yet), but after working on it I realized it is a little rediculous for me to mask bad css with a gigantic PHP function to help me work with the the problematic css. This approach can be seen here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126611/cannot-seem-to-get-a-value-or-key-from-array

So I am wondering if anyone could help me fix my social icons so that if I remove them it will not move their alignment from the center. So it always looks centered and even. Here is a JS fiddle of the icons: http://jsfiddle.net/g2SC4/

Here is a look at the HTML. In total there is 6 icons:

```
<!-- start: social icon -->
<div id="social-icons">
<div class="section-wrapper section-icon social-icon">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="social-icon-phone clear-phone">
                <div class="span1 offset3">
                    <div class="flip-container">
                      <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front">
                          <div class="flip-a">
                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook icon-2x"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          <div class="flip-b facebook">
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon-back"><i class="icon-facebook icon-2x"></i></span></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              

                <div class="span1">
                    <div class="flip-container">
                      <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front ">
                          <div class="flip-a">
                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter icon-2x"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          <div class="flip-b twitter">
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon-back"><i class="icon-twitter icon-2x"></i></span></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="span1">
                    <div class="flip-container">
                      <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front ">
                          <div class="flip-a">
                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-google-plus icon-2x"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          <div class="flip-b google">
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon-back"><i class="icon-google-plus icon-2x"></i></span></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>

            <div class="social-icon-phone clear-phone">
                <div class="span1">
                    <div class="flip-container">
                      <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front ">
                          <div class="flip-a">
                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-github icon-2x"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          <div class="flip-b github">
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon-back"><i class="icon-github icon-2x"></i></span></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="span1">
                    <div class="flip-container">
                      <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front ">
                          <div class="flip-a">
                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-pinterest icon-2x"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          <div class="flip-b pinterest">
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon-back"><i class="icon-pinterest icon-2x"></i></span></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  

                <div class="span1">
                    <div class="flip-container">
                      <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front ">
                          <div class="flip-a">
                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin icon-2x"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          <div class="flip-b linkedin">
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon-back"><i class="icon-linkedin icon-2x"></i></span></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div><!-- end: social icon -->
</div>
```

Comment: maybe use `span:first-child`, `span:nth-child` instead of extra classes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Remove the class `offset3` from the first icon(span) and the following CSS:

```
.social-icon-phone.clear-phone {
    display: inline-block;
}

#social-icons .row {
    text-align: center; // remove margin left -30px
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using this now. It makes a huge difference.